# ATmega328P Serial Communication never fills UDR0 with data

Tags: c, uart, serial-communication, atmega, avr-gcc

I have an ATmega328P connected to a FT232 in which I am trying to read and write data from the micro to a PC application. When I send data to the micro via putty, it acknowledges that there is data coming in, but the value of UDR0 is 0 no matter what serial data is sent in. I have the correct USB driver for the FT232. Below is the code I am currently using.

```cpp
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

#define F_CPU 16000000UL // Define your microcontroller's clock frequency
#define BAUD 115200
#define UBRR_VALUE ((F_CPU / (16UL * BAUD)) - 1)

volatile char receivedChar; // Variable to hold received data

// USART Receive Complete ISR
ISR(USART_RX_vect) {
    receivedChar = UDR0; // Read data from UDR0 register
}

void USART_Init() {
    // Set baud rate
    UBRR0H = (uint8_t)(UBRR_VALUE >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (uint8_t)(UBRR_VALUE);

    // Enable receiver and receiver interrupt
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);

    // Set frame format: 8 data bits, 1 stop bit, no parity
    UCSR0C = (1 << UCSZ01) | (1 << UCSZ00);
}

void USART_TransmitChar(char data) {
    // Wait for empty transmit buffer
    while (!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)));
    
    // Put data into buffer, sends the data
    UDR0 = data;
}

int main() {
    USART_Init(); // Initialize USART
    
    sei(); // Enable global interrupts
    
    while (1) {
        // Main loop
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Essentially, I am just looking to send 8 bit bytes back and forth between putty and the embedded board. It should be noted that this is a custom board with a brand new ATmega328P with an external 16MHz crystal.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". If you have additions or clarifications, please [edit] your question and add them. Please do not port a comment, this is not a forum. -- Off-topic: Are you aware that the baud rate divisor is just 8 with an actual value of 8.68...? This will give you strange received values, if the reception will finally work. Consider to use another crystal frequency or another baud rate.

Comment: `USART_TransmitChar()` never gets called anywhere.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How do you know that `receivedChar` never gets set?  Are you using a debugger to see the value of that variable?  Also, serial has been implemented probably dozens of times for this chip.  I recommend looking at the Arduino core implementation, or some other well-tested implementation.

Comment: I am using an atmel ice. I am stepping through the code and the register only holds a value of 0 and if I set the value of UDR0 to a variable I only get 255 to the assigned var.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with this code:

### 1. UART Transmitter is never activated

In

```cpp
    // Enable receiver and receiver interrupt
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << RXCIE0);
```

the UART receiver (and IRQ) is activated, but not so for the transmitter.

### 2. `USART_TransmitChar` gets never called

Function `USART_TransmitChar` gets never called, and there are no otherplaces that would transmit anything.

### 3. USART Frequency Error is above 0.2% (at 3.5% actually)

With F<sub>CPU</sub> = 16 MHz and Baudrate = 115200, the UART frequency deviates more than 0.2% from the target frequency.  The error is at minimum 3.5% with U2X = 0 and 2.1% with U2X = 1.  Thus, in any case, the error is more than the 10-fold maximal recommended frequency deviation.

---

For the frequency error see for example this small [JavaScript tool to compute UBRR for ATmega](http://gjlay.de/helferlein/avr-uart-rechner.html). Just click on <kbd>16 MHz</kbd> to open a popup that shows UBRR values and associated error rates.